# How do I grep GZ files to extract PNG files?

Tags: grep, png, gzip

Ok, so I have a tone of .GZ files in a folder, and I'm looking to recursively look through each one of them and extract all the PNG files into another destination folder. How would I do that?

EDIT:

I've been using this command from the terminal to find a string in a GZ file and copy the entire file to another destination directory. Then do stuff with it. There's a few drawbacks. One, when I put in "PNG", it finds files such as CSS files that reference "PNG" instead of file types. Second, it doesn't output anything to the directory except for copying the entire file.. I'd like to extract the file instead.

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -lh "png" | xargs -I % cp % /some_destination
```

EDIT:

Here's an example folder structure:

> FILE001.GZ, FILE002.GZ, FILE003.GZ, etc

Not all of them contain PNGs, and some of them contain many files in a folder structure. What I want, is the following in another destination folder:

> 34950560.png, 3959560.png, etc.

Thank you ahead of time!

Comment: gz only contains a single file, so just look for `foo.png.gz`. if they're tar files, then you can't. the filenames are inside the tar, which now gzipped, and you can NOT figure out what randomish bytes `png` became inside that gzipped tar. in other words, you're going to have UNZIP every single tar and list the files inside.

Comment: They're all gz files, so the tar issue isn't an issue. I'm not following what you mean about look for foo.png.gz? Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: `find . -name \*.png.gz`. done

Comment: Nope, that's not it.

Comment: then you should explain exactly what these files. are. `gz kittens.png` will result in `kittens.png.gz`

Comment: Not all of them are PNG files, only some of them. Some of them contain entire folder structures. All I want is the PNG Files extracted into another folder. I did explain that, I said that I had a ton of files, that I wanted the code to look through and extract the PNGs from them..

Comment: if they contain "entier folder structures", then they're not plain gz files. they'd have to be tar.gz

Comment: Ok, so then they're entire tar.gz files.. Is there a way to tweak what I already have, or is there another way entirely?

Comment: so like I said, you can **NOT** grep `.tar.gz` to look for png. the entire tar files has been gzipped, which means the filenames embedded in the tar have become random binary garbage. you'll have to UNZIP the files, then grep

Comment: Ok, I appreciate it.

Comment: I would suggest some method that runs "file" on the contents to ensure that you are getting all the PNG format files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your ".GZ" files are actually gzipped ".tar" archives with multiple files, then you can accomplish your goal in one line:

```
find . -type f -iname '*.GZ' | xargs -n1 -I'{}' tar -C "/path/to/extract" -xf '{}' '*.png' 2>/dev/null
```

Explanation:

- `find . -type f -iname '*.GZ'` : find all .GZ files in the current path (incl. subdirectories). `-iname` means case-insensitive, matching both .gz and .GZ files
- `xargs -n1 -I'{}' <command> '{}'` : call 'command' with at most one argument (`-n1`) from stdin, placing the argument in the placeholder `{}`.
- `tar -C "/path/to/extract" -xf '{}' '*.png'` : Extract from the file got from xargs (`-xf {}`), only files ending in '*.png'. `-C /path/to/extract`: extract files there.
- `2>/dev/null` : Mute the error messages raised from GZ files not-containing .png files.

This command will extract all `.png` files in the specified folder (preserving any directory structures in the original tar.gz files). Identically named `.png` files across multiple archives will be stored only once, i.e. the last extracted `.png` file will overwrite the previous identically-named file. 
If you want to overcome this issue, then you'll need a more complex script like:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

function extract_png() {
    local gzpath=$1; local extract_path=$2
    cd "$gzpath" || return 2
    find . -iname '*.GZ' | 
        while read gzfile; do
            if tar -tf "$gzfile" '*.png' 2>/dev/null; then
                local basename=${gzfile%.*}; basename=${basename##*/}
                local extract_to="$extract_path/$basename"
                mkdir -p "${extract_to}"
                tar -C "$extract_to" -xf "$gzfile" '*.png'
            fi
        done
}

extract_png '/path/to/search' '/path/to/save'
```

The `extract_png` function will save extracted `.png` files to a different subfolder for each archive, under `/path/to/save` (e.g. `/path/to/save/FILE001/`, `/path/to/save/FILE002/` etc).

An explanation about `if tar -tf "$gzfile" '*.png' 2>/dev/null; then ...` : This will return true if there are .png files in the file "$gzfile". The `-t` argument in tar means "list contents". When the specified files (`*.png`) are not included in the archive, `tar -t` prints an error message (hidden by `2>/dev/null`) and returns a non-zero code which evaluates this condition to false.

Comment: Awesome, what a complete answer! I'm going to try this in a few minutes!

Comment: Glad it helped. Note that you can adapt the above to other file types as well (e.g. `*.jpeg`) just changing the corresponding arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You can use file signatures (aka magic numbers). The first few bytes of a PNG file include a file signature to indicate that the file is a PNG. If the files are all gzip'd then there's an extra header from gzip, which we can skip. 
od is a command that will dump parts of a file in a readable format you specify. I tell it to skip the gzip header and dump in a hex format. From my tests, you'll end up with a string "34e6 5580" for the next eight bytes. If it matches the PNG signature, move it to the new directory and rename.

```
COUNTER=0; mkdir PNGDIR
#
for FILE in `ls -1d *`; do  
   od -j 4 -N 10 -x ${FILE} | grep -q "34e6 5580" 
   if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
     COUNTER=`expr 1 + $COUNTER`
     cp ${FILE} PNGDIR/picture_${COUNTER}.png.gz
   fi
done
```

Comment: So that code goes in a BASH file? A .sh file, correct?

Comment: Sure, if you like. 
You can copy and paste it into a commandline as well.

Comment: Fantastic answer. I gave it to the other guy because it was the most complete, but you definitely did a good job answering the question.

Comment: Thanks, WB. Glad that you got something that worked for you. That is some fine looking code, too.